# Silence the `unknown suffix -- ignored` error

Tags: gunzip

In a directory with many subdirectories, I have some `.gz` archives. I want to recursively extract all these archives using `gunzip`. Hence, I use:

```
gunzip -r myDir
```

However, this command exits with `"non-zero exit status 1"` when there are some files in `myDir` that are not archives, with the errors being:

```
gunzip: myDir/dir1/file1.vcf.gz.tbi: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

Any idea how I can silence this particular error/warning?

Comment: There's two pieces: the return code and the error message; which (or both) are you interested in?

Comment: I'm interested in having `gunzip` to skip all non-archive files; hence, exit with status code `0` if the directory contains non-zip files.

Comment: Does `-q` / `--quiet` suppress this?

Comment: What system and gzip version is there? GNU gzip 1.9 seems to be doing just that -- `gunzip -r` silently skips the files which don't have the `.gz` suffix.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach here is not to just suppress the error message but to avoid the error - by something like this:

```
find myDir -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip {} +
```

This uncompresses all files in or under `myDir` that has names that end with `.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect `stderr` (where the messages go) to `/dev/null`:

```
gunzip -r /my/funky/dir 2> /dev/null
```